# Azure DevOps Custom Task - add additional resources required by task

Tags: powershell, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a custom task that is based on a PowerShell script. Within the script I execute an executable (.exe). The related resources (the .exe as well as the .dlls) are provided by the repository used for the Build pipeline (i.e. I reference to the .exe within the PowerShell script).

This approach has the big disadvantage that I have to add the .exe and .dlls to each repository used with a pipeline that includes the custom task.

Is there a way to include the folder with the .exe and related .dlls to the custom task itself? If yes, how does it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple - just add the resources to the task folder like

```
<tasknameFolder>
    <folderWithExecutable>
        <executableName>.exe
        <someDLLName>.dll
    <scriptname>.ps1
    task.json
```

and reference the executable in the PowerShell script like

```
$compilerPath = "folderWithExecutable\someExecutable.exe"
&$compilerPath
```